# How to use function argument as part of variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, google-chrome-extension

This works

```
chrome.storage.local.get('sizePref', function(items) { // Get size preferences from storage
  var sizePref2 = items.sizePref.tops; // Set size to a var
  console.log("You can get this " + sizePref2)
});
```

However, when I try to make it a function

```
function getSize(itemSize) {
  chrome.storage.local.get('sizePref', function(items) { // Get size preferences from storage
    var sizePref = items.sizePref.itemSize;
    return (sizePref);
  });
}
var mySize = getSize(tops);
console.log("This size that u are looking for is " + mySize)
```

it says "tops" is undefined.

Comment: @jfriend00 pointed out a serious issue in his answer - but I think another problem is that function `getSize` isn't returning anything - only the async function `chrome.stroage.local.get` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the property name is in a variable, you use the bracket syntax.  So, instead of this:

```
items.sizePref.itemSize
```

you use this:

```
items.sizePref[itemSize]
```

---

In addition, you cannot return a value synchronously from an async callback.  That logic is just wrong.  So, you can't make a function `getSize()` that will return the result.  The result will not be available until some time LATER after `getSize()` already returns.  You would have to either pass a callback into `getSize()` or have `getSize()` return a promise.

```
function getSize(itemSize) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      chrome.storage.local.get('sizePref', function(items) { // Get size preferences from storage
        resolve(items.sizePref[itemSize]);
  });
}

getSize("whatever").then(function(result) {
    // code that uses the result here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with promises (viz. unlikely) then you can use callbacks too. I personally think promises are a better way to solve your issue.

```
function getSize(itemSize, callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.get('sizePref', function(items) { 
    // Get size preferences from storage
    var sizePref = items.sizePref[itemSize]; //thanks @jfriend00
    callback (sizePref); //thanks at @Kevin Friedheim
  });
}
var mySize = getSize(tops, function (mySize) {
    console.log("This size that u are looking for is " + mySize)
});
```